# Geometry vectorial

Tags: geometry

Consider the lines $L_{1} = \{(2t, 3t - 1, t) \mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $L_{2} = \{(-t, 2t + 1,- 2t + 3) \mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Calculate the Cartesian equations of two parallel planes $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}$ such that $L_{1}\subset \pi_{1}$ and $L_{2} \subset \pi_{2}$.

I used the cross product, but that don't find the plans equations

Answer (score 3):

$\ell$ is a line with direction $\langle 2,3,1\rangle$ and passing $(0, -1, 0)$;
$m$  is a line with direction $\langle-1, 2, -2\rangle$ and passing $(0, 1, 3)$.
So the vertical normal vector of the two parallel planes is:
$$\langle2, 3, 1\rangle \times \langle-1, 2, -2\rangle = \langle-8, 3, 7\rangle$$
so the two planes:
$$ \pi_1: -8x + 3y + 7z + 3 = 0;$$
$$ \pi_2: -8x + 3y + 7z - 24 = 0$$